# I keep getting alerted regarding unread Facebook messages even though there is none

Tags: notifications, facebook

My phone beeps and tells me I have an unread Facebook message even though I don't. I've got a hunch what the source of the problem is. I have both the Facebook app and the Friend Caster app and they are connected to different Facebook accounts (one's for work one's for my personal life). Is there way I can stop getting these false "new message" alerts?

I want both my Facebook accounts on my phone because then all the contact numbers get pulled off both accounts. If anyone can think of a better way I'm open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Friend Caster is considered end of life so that may be the problem. Facebook apparently made changes to their api, so it has been discontinued. Source https://support.onelouder.com/hc/en-us/articles/204558634-What-Happened-to-FriendCaster-

You should be able to have 1 account on the app and one on the preferred web browser, or you could go the route this page talks about https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/set-up-two-different-facebook-accounts-one-android-device-0161254/

There are probably other workarounds but these are the ones I found with a quick google search.